# block as argument to method in ruby is a mystery?

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments, block

```
3.times {puts "Hello"}
```

outputs:

> Hello
>      Hello
>      Hello

we understand it as `times` is a function in `Integer` class that takes a `block` as argument.

I tried to dig in and found that it isn't that simple.

if it is the case that `times` is a function and parenthesis in a method call is optional I tried to validate it using:

```
3.times({puts "Hello"})
```

it threw an error obviously:

> SyntaxError: (irb):3: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
>   3.times({puts "Hello"})
>                  ^
>   (irb):3: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input
>   3.times({puts "Hello"})
>                         ^
>       from /home/ashish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/irb:12:in `'

further investigating:

```
a = 3.times
puts a.class
```

Outputs `Enumerator` that implies that 3.times is an `Enumerator` class object.

Can someone explain the entire thing with exact concept behind this?

Comment: Block "arguments" are syntactic sugar; if you do it inside the parens it will try to parse as a hash.

Comment: what if we try `3.times (do puts "hello" end)` in this case why will it try to parse it as hash.

Comment: `3.times(&proc {puts "Hello"})`

Comment: What is the problem is with `times` taking a block?

Comment: block as argument is wrong whereas reference to block as an argument is correct which actually returns a proc object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sawa says, blocks aren't objects, and thus aren't passed as arguments. Blocks are a special thing in Ruby. They have special syntax (which only allows us to pass one block to a method) and a special keyword dedicated to calling them. Here's an example implementation of `times` in Ruby:

```
def times
  if block_given?
    i = 0
    while i < self
      yield i
      i += 1
    end
    # times returns the number that was executing times,
    # so we need to return self here
    self
  else
    enum_for :times
    # ^^ This is where the Enumerator comes from if
    #    you don't pass a block.
  end
end
```

The `block_given?` method tests if there is a block associated with the current method, and the `yield` keyword calls the block.

Answer (score 2):

A block is not an argument, it is not even an object. Putting it in parenthesis is meaningless because it is not an object.

Comment: it is an argument, just a positional one and with syntactic sugar which allows you to omit `&` and `proc`.

Comment: your statements are contradictory.
`A block is not an argument` and `times taking a block`
taking as what a method will take something as argument only.

Comment: @VictorMoroz With your logic, it follows that a woman is a man that can be a woman without MtoF gender reassignment operation.

Comment: @sawa parts highlighted `A block is not an argument` and `what the problem is with times taking a block.` what do you mean by times taking block taking as what?

Comment: @sawa I agree with first sentence of your answer. Anyhow parenthesis is meaningful to identify a block.

Comment: @AshishChopra "[A] method will take something as argument only" is your own stipulation. Argumentation based on your stipulation leading to a contradiction does not mean my statement is contradictory.

Comment: @AlokAnand As I wrote, a block cannot be used with parentheses.

Comment: block is a set of instructions, which can be executed n number of times

Comment: @AshishChopra Functions can take arguments, and optionally a block. You can pass a block-like thing, e.g., a Proc *as* an argument, which is what the block syntax actually does. But when you use the block form it (a) can't go inside the parens because of Ruby's grammar, and (b) it's *transformed* to a block argument--but in itself it isn't an argument. It sounds better in my head.

Comment: @sawa by parenthesis I meant curly braces {}, sorry for generalizing it.

Answer (score 0):

Block is a positional (always the last one if defined) argument with a special rule for passing value, `times` can be defined as:

```
def times(&block)
  block.call(...)
end
```

to call it you need an object that can be converted to an instance of `Proc` class and you should prepend it with `&`:

```
3.times(&Proc.new { puts "Hello" })
```

Calling `times` like

```
3.times { puts "Hello" }
```

is just a syntactic sugar for the above form.

**UPDATE**: I have to admit that it's not a syntactic sugar, blocks are faster and just adding `&block` parameter to `times` does slow things down even if it's never called.

Comment: It's not exactly syntactic sugar. What `3.times { puts "Hello" }` actually does is a lot simpler than `3.times(&Proc.new { puts "Hello" })`. Both have the same ultimate effect, but wrapping and unwrapping and wrapping and unwrapping a proc like you do here involves a lot more work under the hood. Also, saying that "block is a positional argument" is a little bit deceptive. That's only true from the standpoint of the language if you choose to wrap it in a Proc.

Comment: An argument must be an object. A block is not an object. **Proof:** If a block were an object, it should be an `Object` instance, and should respond to the method `object_id`. However, `{puts "foo"}.object_id` raise a syntax error. Hence, the assumption that a block were an object was wrong. QED.

Comment: @sawa I've always though it's called syntactic sugar. `block` inside my version of `times` has both class and `object_id`. Simple example: `some_method(:a => 1)`. `:a => 1.object_id` ? Where are those braces?

Comment: Leaving off the braces on a Hash literal *is* syntactic sugar. But blocks are special language construct.

Comment: @Chuck Blocks are implicit arguments, which is probably a more correct term than "positional". If you make them explicit you'll see that what gets passed into the method is a `Proc` without any wrapping to do on your side: `def foo(&block) ; block.class ; end; foo {} #=> Proc`.

Comment: @MichaelKohl, @NeilSlater The moment you put `&` in front of a block, you are not using a block by itself. `&` is a literal that converts a block into a `Proc`. When you have `def foo(&block)`, `foo` is not receiving `block`, but `&block`, which is indeed a `Proc` object, and is an argument.

Comment: @NeilSlater: It is incontrovertible that the `&block` form is syntactic sugar for wrapping the block in a Proc and having it passed as an argument instead of as a block. That is literally what happens.

Comment: block can not be passed as an argument, it is reference to block which  can be passed as an argument which actually is a proc object.

Comment: it is not syntactic sugar.

Comment: To some of you: Don't forget that `&` is not just for a block. It converts whatever follows it into a proc object, as long as it responds to `to_proc`. `&:foo` expands to `->x{x.foo}`.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake above. `&` switches a block and an object. When a block follows, it converts it into a `Proc` object. When an object follows it, it converts it into a block (which is not an object).

Comment: I guess it's semantics. If you look at the actual C source for `rb_block_struct` you'll see that the struct has a member `VALUE proc`. So a block is not a `Proc`, but it includes one. http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/vm_core.h#453